# VBA Run-time error -2147319767 (80028029)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having problems With my Excel-files/VBA code. I'm updating a lot of Excel files (copy/paste into tables) and updating pivot-tables in these files. I've been using this code/Method for years, and it's been working just fine.

But recently my files has been acting strangely after running VBA. When updating 35 excel files, around 15 of these are "corrupt" after an update. I can open them up, but I can't store. Then files just shut Down.

So I changed my line "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" into "True", and ran again. And this time VBA stops displaying: 
Run-time error '-2147319767 (80028029): Automation error.
And it Points to this line:

```
For Each pt In sh_ske_beløp.PivotTables
```

This is just one out of 12 sheets that I update in exactly the same way (entire code is like this):

```
For Each pt In sh_ske_beløp.PivotTables
pt.RefreshTable
Next pt
```

I'm completely lost! This bit of code should be a no-brainer! And I just can't figure out what's wrong. I'm doing the "Option Explicit"-bit at the top, without any errors. I'm not doing anything Advanced, just opening up files and copying/pasting data between workbooks/sheets and updating pivot-tables. There's no "Userform" going on here. Nothing is "missing" in the Tools/References menu.
The code is running on Windows 10 64-bit using Excel 365 64 bit. Every available update has been installed.

Comment: I think that you cant use unicode characters in variables

Comment: Sounds complicated. Question: are the files saving to a regular folder on the computer/network or are they going to a cloud solution like OneDrive? I've had issues in the past saving properly to OneDrive... though not with the files being corrupted.

Comment: Files are opened from lokal drive, and stored at the same Place. No cloud going on here. However, I'm not sure I've used a sheet name holding the norwegian letter "ø" before. I'll try to change it and re-run (but it might take me some hours to change it)... :-)

Comment: @kit99 you don't need to change the name of the sheet. Just the variable holding the sheet.

Answer (score 3):

> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sh_ske_beløp").PivotTables

try run this code

```
Sub test()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim shtName As String
Dim pt As PivotTable
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
shtName = "sh_ske_beløp"
For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
    If sht.Name = shtName Then
        For Each pt In sht.PivotTables
            pt.RefreshTable
        Next pt
    End If
Next sht
If Not wsExists(shtName, wb) Then MsgBox shtName & " NotExist!!!"
End Sub

Function wsExists(wsName As String, wb As Workbook) As Boolean
Dim ws
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        wsExists = (wsName = ws.Name): If wsExists Then Exit Function
    Next ws
End Function
```

**VBA Variables**

Variables are specific values that are stored in a computer memory or storage system. Later, you can use that value in code and execute. The computer will fetch that value from the system and show in the output. Each variable must be given a name.

To name the variable in VBA, you need to follow the following rules.

- It must be less than 255 characters
- No spacing is allowed
- It must not begin with a number
- Period is not permitted
- No DOT allowed
- NO Unicode allowed

Comment: i think you are right that this is likely the cause

Comment: Ok, I've now renamed all definitions holding the Norwegian letters "æ", "ø" and "å" (found several!). But the code stops again at the same line as above... Do I have to remove all these letters from sheet names as well? (All tho' it is stated above that it shouldn't be necessary.)

Comment: I've done some more testing. First I removed all code set to refresh any pivottables. Then the VBA runs through without any errors, but files still crash when opening/storing after the vba-run. Then I ran the same code on different Win/Office configurations. One time in Windows 10 server/Office 2016 32-bit. And one time in Windows 7 server/ Office 2016 32-bit (vdi configuration). Same problem. The vba runs through without any errors, but when I try to open up files some of them are corrupted. For some of them I can open, but not store (excel has experienced a problem and must shut down)...

Comment: ... So I have to assume that there is something in my excel-files that's not as it is supposed to be. It's not the same files that crash every time, but they vary. How can I nail down what excel is stuck on? There's no help in the "must shut down"-message!