# VBA macro does not recognize sheets in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am an experienced VBA coder who have a workbook with 20 worksheets. When I run macros on this workbook, only some worksheets are identified. I don't understand why Excel won't find all worksheets that indeed exists in this workbook. All sheets are visible and not password protected. To troubleshoot I have made a test code that captures the problem:

```
Sub Test()
Dim w As Worksheet

For Each w In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(w.Name).Cells(1, 1).Value = "TEST"
Next

End Sub
```

This code loops through 2 of the 20 worksheets and returns the string TEST in cell A1, as expected. On worksheet no. 3 I, however, get the following error message (I apologize for the part of the message that is written in Norwegian):

"Run-time error '-2147319767 (80028029)':

Automation error
Ugyldig sendereferanse, eller referanse til ukomplisert type."

What causes this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `w`is already a worksheet, so `w.Cells(1, 1).Value = "TEST"` should work.

Comment: Are you using unicode characters in the worksheet names? (see e. E. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55625646/17172829) )

Comment: I just tried that and it correctly sets the value in each worksheet. Try stepping through the macro to find out exactly where it stops.

Comment: It stops on "ThisWorkbook.Sheets(w.Name).Cells(1, 1).Value = "TEST"" when arriving to sheet no. 3. Sheet names are regular english letters found on your keyboard.

Comment: The Sheets collection also includes charts. Be consistent and always use one collection i.e. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(w.Name).Cells(1, 1).Value = "TEST"`. But Shrotter's suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: If you follow Shrotter's advice and the problem still occurs then your workbook could be corrupt. Several ways of recovering it are discussed here https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/vnnkh9/runtime_error_2147319767_80028029_automation/

Comment: Thanks! That reddit thread had the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to say without seeing your workbook, but be aware that the Sheets collection is not the same as the Worksheets collection.  For example, Sheets includes "Chart Sheets" as well as Worksheets.  And a Chart Sheet probably doesn't have a Cells property.

If you step through your test code with the debugger and examine the "w" object you may be able to see what's happening.

I suggest you avoid mixing the Sheets collection and the Worksheets collection.  I.e. you could change your test code to:

```
Sub Test()
Dim w As Worksheet

For Each w In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(w.Name).Cells(1, 1).Value = "TEST"
Next
End Sub
```

or even better:

```
Sub Test()
Dim w As Worksheet

For Each w In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    w.Cells(1, 1).Value = "TEST"
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Using Worksheets instead of Sheets didn't work. Don't have any "Chart Sheets", just 20 regular sheets with strings, numbers and references to other sheets (in the same workbook).

Unfortunately, I can't reveal the code due to confidentiality concerns. However, what I try to say with my test code, is that Excel won't recognise certain worksheets. So, when I try to call them, I get this error mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

@Chill60 found the solution:

In VBA editor:

-Go to Tools, References

-Activate "AccessibilitycplAdmin 1.0 type admin"

For some reason, Excel now recognizes all worksheets.